# Working with time displayed as strings

Tags: java

Alright so I'm taking an AP Computer Science course and up until now I've found the content easy and unchallenging because I already had a background in Java. However now I have run into an issue with some of the code that the course is providing me with and writing a function based off of it. I've googled it, and tested many different things to try and get it to work and to no avail. So hopefully you guys can shed some light on this and perhaps help me figure it out.

First the book provides me with this code as a basic Time class:

```
public class Time extends Object {          
private int itsHour;          
private int itsMin;         
/** Create an object for the given hour and minute. If min          
* is negative, adjust the values to make 0 <= min < 60. */    
public Time (int hour, int min) { // constructor    
    super(); 

    itsHour = hour; 

    for (itsMin = min; itsMin < 0; itsMin = itsMin + 60) {

          itsHour--; 

    }

} //======================= 

/** Return the time expressed in military time. */ 

public String toString()  { 

      if (itsHour < 10) {

            return ("0" + itsHour) + itsMin; 

      } else {

            return ("" + itsHour) + itsMin; 
      } 
 }
    /** Return the result of adding this Time to that Time. */ 
    public Time add (Time that) {
         // Read below at issue #2 
    }
}
```

That was the main class they gave us to work with and then they gave a class called TimeTester which is to be used to execute the commands. The comments dictate what should happen.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 

class TimeTester { 
      public static void main (String[] args) { 
            Time t1 = new Time (13, 25); 
            Time t2 = new Time (8, -150); 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "1 " + t1.toString()); 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "2 " + t2.toString()); 
            Time t3 = t1.add (t2); 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "3 " + t3.toString()); 
            t1 = t2.add (t3); 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "1 " + t1.toString()); 
            System.exit (0); 
       } //======================= 
}
```

Now like I said this code was literally handed to me it's making sense of the code and getting it to work for me that I just literally cannot do. So below are basically the key issues I'm running into.

1) I understand how its supposed to run and what the executors do, but I do not understand what exactly its doing to achieve the results.

2) The add function in the first set of code which was basically it's main class is the main part of the assignment. The assignment reads as follows:

> Exercise 4.15 (harder) Write the Time method public Time add (Time
>   that):  The executor returns a new Time object that is the sum of the
>   two, e.g., 0740 add 1430 is 
>   2210. If the sum is more than 2359, drop the extra 24 hours, e.g., 1300 add 1400 is 300.
>   Assigned from: http://www.cs.ccsu.edu/~jones/chap04.pdf

When I carry over the values to the add function in the TimeTester executing "now.add(wait)" I go to pull that result using "that" but the values don't pull forward.

I've also tried to change up the functions to perhaps get my own understanding and make it work for me. I changed the Time later call in the TimeTester, and then edited the function add to accept 2 values. Then added this code to the add function:

```
public Time add (Time time1, Time time2) {
        String t1String = time1.toString(); // Value is: "0730"
        String t2String = time2.toString(); // Value is: "0245"
        int t1convert = Integer.parseInt(t1String, 2); // Value is 730
        int t2convert = Integer.parseInt(t2String, 2); // Value is: 245
        int total = t1convert + t2convert; // Value added together is: 1015
        return total; // Return value of total
    }
```

So my call looked like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
        now = new Time (7, 30); // 7:30 in the morning 
        wait = new Time (2, 45); // 2 hours 45 minutes 
        later = now.add (now, wait); // produces 10:15 in the morning 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, now + " + " + wait + " = " + later.toString());
        System.exit (0); 
    }
```

However all that code would not compile and produce a result which could be returned to my `TimeTester`, it always produced a compile error of "incompatible types" referring to my return total; line. So it obviously cannot return Integers. So I am just absolutely stuck on what to do to make it add the two times.

3) I cannot use the built in Java time functions where it's formatted with semicolons. I know how to do that part which is why this different way is driving me up the wall.

4) I don't want you to write my code for me, I'd like to gain a better understanding of it and perhaps have my mistakes pointed out so that I can comprehend what in the world is going on with it.

I know it's a long post, but when I ask for help I like to be descriptive and provide everything I can because I know it's going to help me better in the long run and hopefully help the person who helps me track down an answer fast.

(PS. All of this is compiled and ran in a program called BlueJ. It's an online course so I have no instructor in class to ask about it all we have is a monitor.)

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger or added println calls to see how the variables change?

Comment: hint: the exercise says to write a "Time method public Time add (Time that)". That is, this method goes inside the Time class, is public, has a Time object as single argument, and returns a (possibly new, possibly not) Time object. It does not ask you to write a method `add(time1,time2)`.

Comment: @Mark Running the timeTester with the only thing with "public Time add (Time that) { return that; } } " Allows the program to execute and run however when it does the popup to display result it produces the output: "0730 + 0245 = 0730" which means it is returning the executor as is expected. Which tells that my return MUST be a Time accept value. However, I am unsure of how to add anything in my add function to produce a "Time" value. So I've tested the base code but as soon as it gets to writing my add function to produce something the compiler will take is where I get lost.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I did that to try and achieve a result based on my own personal guesses. I could not figure out a way to work it the way they had it so i experimented. I included it in the post to ensure I wasn't gonna get flamed for asking for assignment help.

Comment: I changed my function to reflect what the book wanted and I now receive a different error: 

    "public Time add (Time that) { Time total = this + that; }" The error received reads: bad operand types for binary operator '+' first type: Time; second type: Time

Comment: yes, you are writing the add method. There is no "+" operation, you need to make the add method generate a new Time object with the correctly summed new minute and hour values. That will require a new Time(...) with `hour` and `minutes` arguments based on `this.hour` and `that.hour`, and `this.minutes` and `that.minutes`, respectively.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Looking at your comment i managed to write this line of code to see if i could execute it that way and I cannot. "Time t1 = new Time(this.hour, that.hour); " spits out "cannot find symbol - variable hour". Any insight into this?

Comment: @user1686765 That's because the class fields are named `itsHour` and `itsMin`.  You don't have as much Java background as you think. Go back and study how a Java `class` works.

Comment: @user1686765 where is your variable hour in your class `Time` ? There is none, so it's not going to work. It should be `this.itsHour`. Anyway, you are probably not right with the method that has two inputs as you are not meant to change the exercise for your own comfort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a method to add two `Time` instances (`a` and `b`) and return a new `Time` instance; such a method would look like the inverse of the provided `Time` constructor loop, `for (itsMin = min; itsMin < 0; itsMin = itsMin + 60)`, specifically - it should increment some hours count (perhaps by adding the hours from a and b) while the number of minutes is `> 59` and subtracting 60 minutes at a time... This method might look something like this

```
public static Time add(Time a, Time b) {   // Add two Time(s) together.
  if (a == null) {                         // if a is null, just return b.
    return b;
  } else if (b == null) {                  // if b is null, just return a.
    return a;
  }
  int hours = a.itsHour + b.itsHour;       // Add the hours together.
  int minutes = a.itsMin + b.itsMin;       // Add the minutes together.
  for (; minutes > 59; minutes -= 60) {    // Increment hours as necessary, while
                                           // decrementing the minute count by 60.
    hours++;
  }
  return new Time(hours, minutes);         // Return the new Time instance.
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Time now = new Time(7, 30);              // 7:30 in the morning
  Time wait = new Time(2, 45);             // 2 hours 45 minutes
  Time later = Time.add(now, wait);        // produces 10:15 in
                                           // the morning
  System.out.println(later);              
}
```

Outputs

```
1015
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is complaining that you are returning an int, when you defined the function return type to be "Time":

```
public Time add (Time time1, Time time2) {
        String t1String = time1.toString(); // Value is: "0730"
        String t2String = time2.toString(); // Value is: "0245"
        int t1convert = Integer.parseInt(t1String, 2); // Value is 730
        int t2convert = Integer.parseInt(t2String, 2); // Value is: 245
        int total = t1convert + t2convert; // Value added together is: 1015
        return total; // Return value of total
    }
```

The return type is Time:

- public **Time** add (Time time1, Time time2) ...

You return "total", which is of type "int":

- **int** total = t1convert + t2convert;
- return **total**; …

What you would need to do is to make a new Time object which has the answer stored inside of it. For example:

- **Time** t3 = new Time(0, total);  // *This is assuming that "total" represents the minutes*

Regarding the issue in the comment,

> @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Looking at your comment i managed to write this
>   line of code to see if i could execute it that way and I cannot. "Time
>   t1 = new Time(this.hour, that.hour); " spits out "cannot find symbol -
>   variable hour". Any insight into this? – user1686765 3 mins ago

"this.hour" is looking at the current Time instance, which is a instance of the Time class, for a member variable called "hour." If you go to your Time class, you will see that it only has some methods and 2 variables called "itsHour" and "itsMin". So it cannot find the variable "hour" because it does not exist. I think you meant to put "this.itsHour" in place of "this.hour".

Comment: I had actually worked my way along to get something similar to what you are providing. However in practice this is failing. It's outputting a NumberFormatException because when we deal with the numbers from Time they are forwarded into a string as 0730 - a value which is invalid for an integer. Is there anyway to drop the 0 so it does not throw this error?

Comment: Can you copy/paste the code and compiler error for me to look at?

Comment: Error reads: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "072" (in java.lang.NumberFormatException) 

Code is: `public Time add (Time that) {
        Time t1 = new Time(this.itsHour, that.itsHour);
        Time t2 = new Time(this.itsMin, that.itsMin);
        String t1String = t1.toString();
        String t2String = t2.toString();
        int t1Int = Integer.parseInt(t1String, 2);
        int t2Int = Integer.parseInt(t2String, 2);
        Time t3 = new Time(t1Int, t2Int);
        return t3;
    }`

Google says that the error is due to the 0's at the front of the strings.

Comment: I finally figured it out. For the Integer.parseInt method, the second argument is supposed to be the radix of the first argument. So, if the string is in base 10, then the second argument needs to be 10. In your case, the second argument is 2. That means that it is interpreting the first string argument as binary. Because binary is only 0's and 1's, and your string argument contains non-zero and/or non-one digits, it throws the error. If you change it to "Integer.parseInt(t1String, 10);" (etc.) it should fix it. Let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Well it allowed the program to execute, however the result that it produces is incorrect now. I ran some debugging to find the values as they are ran into the add function, converted to new time objects, to string, and final to int. The values in the end make zero sense. Here's the output if your interested: `Values passed to add function: 
0730
0245
Values after made into new time objects: 
072
3045
Values after made into new time objects, and converted to strings: 
072
3045
Values after made into new time objects, and converted to strings, then to Int: 
72
3045
`